# Cumulative formula of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, exponential-function

I'm looking for the cumulative form of the following series:

$\sum_{i} (A+Bi)(2^i-C)$

A, B and C are all constants.

Not a mathematician by breed-- got the formula this far. Feels that it has something to do with binomial expansions, but can't put it together. Sorry if a naive question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}\sum_{i=1}^N(A+Bi)(2^i-C)&= \left(\sum_{i=1}^N 2^i(A+Bi)\right)-C\left(\sum_{i=1}^N(A+Bi) \right) \end{align}

Notice that $\left(\sum_{i=1}^N(A+Bi) \right)$ is just an arithmetic sum.

Now, to handle the first term:
Let 
$$S=\sum_{i=1}^N 2^i(A+Bi)$$

$$2S=\sum_{i=1}^N 2^{i+1}(A+Bi)=\sum_{i=2}^{N+1}2^i(A+Bi-B)$$

$$S=2S-S=2^{N+1}(A+BN)-2(A+B)-B\sum_{i=2}^N2^i$$

Hence \begin{align}S&=2^{N+1}(A+BN)-2(A+B)-4B\sum_{i=0}^{N-2}2^i 
\\&=2^{N+1}(A+BN)-2(A+B)-4B(2^{N-1}-1)\\\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

The distributive law is your friend, here.

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{i=1}^n (A+Bi)(2^i-C)
&=\sum_{i=1}^n(A2^i-AC+Bi2^i-BCi)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^nA2^i-\sum_{i=1}^n AC+\sum_{i=1}^nBi2^i-\sum_{i=1}^n BCi\\
&=A\sum_{i=1}^n2^i-AC\sum_{i=1}^n 1+B\sum_{i=1}^ni2^i-BC\sum_{i=1}^n i\\
&=A\sum_{i=1}^n2^i-AC\sum_{i=1}^n 1+B\sum_{i=1}^ni2^i-BC\sum_{i=1}^n i\\
&=A(2^{n+1}-1)-ACn+B\sum_{i=1}^ni2^i-BCn(n+1)/2\\
\end{array}
$

All the sums are easy except
$s(n)
=\sum_{i=1}^ni2^i
$.

The more general formula is
$\sum_{k=1}^n kx^k
=\dfrac{nx^{n+2}-(n+1)x^{n+1}+x}{(x-1)^2}
$.
Setting $x=2$,
$\sum_{k=1}^n k2^k
=n2^{n+2}-(n+1)2^{n+1}+2
$.

You can now evaluate your sum.

Comment: thx for the answer. first post gets the accept.

Comment: You can always upvote others.